# How can I move an object in Macromedia Flash MX by incrementing its coordinates using ActionScript?

Tags: javascript, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to programatically move an object by incrementing its coordinates through action script. I am relatively new to programming in general. So i want to understand it at a grassroot level.

Comment: In AS3 you can use Tween class, but this is GREAT source to really learn it: http://robertpenner.com/easing/penner_chapter7_tweening.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Its simple in as2

click on the shape drawing

then press F8

select movieclip and press ok

double click the object

in the first frame enter the following

```
this.onEnterFrame = function(){
  _x += 5;
  _y += 5;
};
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>enter</kbd> to test